# PHP/SQL noob, all users seem to connect to DB?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trouble connecting to a db. I'm on a Mac, OSX, XAMPP latest version. I haven't messed with the users and privileges settings in PHP MyAdmin so everything is as it came with the package.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. created a testDB via PHP MyAdmin
2. created a "users" table inside it, 5 columns, ID, user, paass, name, surname
3. inserted 2 rows, Alex and Billy, via MyAdmin
4. trying to connect via PHP to the database

With this code:

```
$conn_error = 'Could not connect.';
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';

mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die($conn_error);
echo "Connected to database.";
```

This returns "Connected to database." However, if I change the user from 'root' to 'anythingElse' - it still connects?! Also, 'OR die()' part of the code doesn't seem to do anything i.e. it doesn't kill the rest of the page if I input wrong user or pass.

What am I doin wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You are beginner . I would advice you to use `Mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql()` functions. It is the right time to transform

Comment: Thank you CyberBoy! The trouble is - I am learning through some NewBoston tutorials that a friend of mine gave me and this is what was in the videos. I'll look into this, thank you once again!

Answer (score -1):

try this ..Hope it helps

```
         <?php

            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db("yourdb name",$con);

            // Check connection
            if ($con)
              {
              echo "connected to database";
              }
            else
            {
           echo "not connected to database";
             }

            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

Comment: This is the reply I get if I use this code you gave me: "Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/probniphp/db_proba.php on line 21
connected to database"

Comment: Found the solution that works - '1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}' (weird I put single quot marks but it doesn't show up as code?

Comment: @AlexStarbuck ,i have changed code a little bit..check that was similar to the code that i gave you

Comment: I know, thanks I appreciate your effort! ;). I'm still struggling though. I understang what mysqli is and what it does but there's something weird with my setup - one minute it works, then I change the username (to try and produce an error and test if all works properly), then I get this "Fatal error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in..." Ahh... :(

Comment: @AlexStarbuck ,Glad it worked finally.Since you got the correct answer ,mark the answer which I showd as correct ,so that others do not struggle with same kind of errore ..Any thanks :)

Comment: I cant, if I try and click the "up" arrow next to your reply I get the message that I need at leaast reputation 15 (?) to mark a reply UP and 25 to mark it DOWN. Maybe Im doing something wrong?